# How to trigger data collection with SiteCatalyst?

Tags: javascript, adobe-analytics

I just get started with Adobe SiteCatalyst and I am just wondering how could I trigger the sending of colllected data to the server with it.
Imagine the situation that I have some custom event, for example event1 = 'user opened help us popup'. After user opens popup - I'm assigning data to props:

```
s.events = "event1";
s.prop1 = "name of popup";
```

After that I'm checking the analytics debugger (`https://www.adobetag.com/d1/digitalpulsedebugger/live/DPD.js`) and it says that I didn't get this data.I suppose that I need somehow send it to SiteCatalyst, but I can't figure out how. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two triggers for Adobe Analytics: page view `s.t()` and click/event `s.tl()`

Based on your scenario, you are probably going to want to use the [`s.tl()`](http://microsite.omniture.com/t2/help/en_US/sc/implement/function_tl.html) trigger.

Here is an example of what the code should look like:

```
s.events = "event1";
s.prop1 = "name of popup";
s.linkTrackVars = "events,prop1";
s.linkTrackEvents = "event1";
s.tl(true,'o','popup opened');
```

The vars you want to be tracked in the `s.tl()` call should be listed in `linkTrackVars`. If there is more than one, delimit with a comma (no spaces, no `s` namespace). If you have any events to track, you must also specify the events in `s.linkTrackEvents`. Basically, `s.linkTrackEvents` should be the same value as `s.events` (*except if you are serializing an event, do NOT include the serialization ID in* `s.linkTrackEvents`)

As for the [`s.tl()`](http://microsite.omniture.com/t2/help/en_US/sc/implement/function_tl.html) call, above is an example of what you might pass for a general event, but args will vary depending on what you are trying to track. (refer to link for details).